# Mapping primary keys of 2 different tables to one another in Entity Framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I am using Entity Framework 4.3.1 code first.  I have 2 tables in my database with their column names listed:

Statuses table:

```
StatusID int
Status varchar(50)
```

RequestStatuses table:

```
RequestStatusID int
RequestStatus varchar(50)
```

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Status : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public RequestStatus RequestStatus { get; set; }
}

public class RequestStatus : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

My database context class:

```
public class ICaseDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
     public DbSet<RequestStatus> RequestStatuses { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StatusConfiguration());
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RequestStatusConfiguration());
     }
}
```

Their configurations:

```
class StatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Status>
{
     internal StatusConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("Statuses");
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("StatusID");
          this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Status");
     }
}

class RequestStatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestStatus>
{
     internal RequestStatusConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("RequestStatuses");
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("RequestStatusID");
          this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("RequestStatus");
     }
 }
```

The data in each table is like this:

RequestStatuses table:

```
RequestStatusID     RequestStatus
1                   RequestStatus1
2                   RequestStatus2
3                   RequestStatus3
4                   RequestStatus4
```

Statuses table:

```
StatusID            Status
1                   Status1
2                   Status2
3                   Status3
4                   Status4
```

The primary key of each table matches the primary key in the other table.  So if I have a request status of RequestStatus1 then the corresponding status must be Status1.  If I have a status of Status3 then the corresponding request status must be RequestStatus3.

Is this possible?

How do I set thtis up in EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a 1:1 mapping, so both ends are required, using Id's as the key.

Updating your configurations like this will create the tables you want:

```
class StatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Status>
{
    internal StatusConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Statuses");
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("StatusID");
        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Status");

        this.HasRequired(x => x.RequestStatus)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();

    }
}

class RequestStatusConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<RequestStatus>
{
    internal RequestStatusConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("RequestStatuses");
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("RequestStatusID");
        this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("RequestStatus");

        this.HasRequired(x => x.Status)
           .WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.  Just 2 questions.. How does EF know to map the 2 primary keys? And how would the code look like if I wanted to map to 2 other fields to each other instead of the ids?

Comment: It works because of how you're setting up the RequiredDependant and RequiredPrincipal mappings - by putting these on, EF makes the assumptions that are needed.  If you want to map to other fields, you would add a .map(m => m.MapKey("KeyName") to the end of the fluent mapping